# How to know the url in UIPasteboard.general.URL is valid?

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

If the url get from UIPasteboard.general.URL is always valid URL? My requirement is if the string in UIPasteboard is a valid url, I will show "Paste and Go", if not, I will show "Paste and Search".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIPasteboard URL` is of type `URL?`. This means if it is a non-nil value then it must be a valid URL. You can't create a `URL` from an invalid URL.

But "valid" here means it has the proper syntax for a URL. It has a valid scheme such a https or file or mailto, etc. And the scheme has other parts that seem to be correct.

But a "valid" `URL` doesn't mean it is going to give you good results. For example, `http://ThisIsNotARealDomain.com/fake/fake.html` is a "valid" URL but putting that in a browser won't give you anything useful.

Is `UIPasteboard.general.URL` is non-nil, attempt to load the URL and check the result. If it fails, you could opt to then attempt a search.